# VBS Check if Window is Open

Tags: vbscript

I am looking for the process in which a vbscript can check if a specific named window is opened and then run the following.

objShell.SendKeys ("^{w}")

I'm still new at this so any help will be appreciated.

thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that VBScript is the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is to look at something like:

```
Const TimeToAllowActivationToComplete = 250 ' YMMV so experiment
WshShell.AppActivate "Put Window Title Here"
Wscript.Sleep TimeToAllowActivationToComplete
WshShell.SendKeys "^{w}"
```

See also web search on "vbscript appactivate sendkeys" with results like:

[ASP Free Forums > System Administration > Windows Scripting VBScript - SendKey to Application in APPActivcate](http://forums.aspfree.com/windows-scripting-64/sendkey-to-application-in-appactivcate-248918.html)

[PC Tools Scripting Home > > WScript Methods SendKeys Method](http://www.pctools.com/guides/scripting/detail/149/?act=reference)